# How to have text on right and left of div

Tags: html, header, containers

I am trying to make a header with an image on the left and links on the left.

Essentially, the below:

[LOGO HERE]                                                                                         Link1 Link2 Link3

I am trying to use divs instead of tables, how do I go about this while keeping 'fluidity'.?

here is my css for the container:

```
.container {
    width: 85%;
    max-width: 1260px;
    min-width: 680px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This is my css for the header:

```
.header {
    background: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
}
.header2 {
    float: right;
    width:49%;

}
```

Header is for the image, header2 is for the text.

Here is how I call it:

```
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><a href="http://www.college.edu"><img src="http://newhope.edu/images/Logo.png" alt="" name="" width="40%"  id="Insert_logo" style="background: #FFF; display:block;"  /></a> 
   <div class="header2">
   test
   </div>
    <!-- end .header --></div>
```

If you would like to see the rest of the code, let me know.

I have tried making my own class, as seen by header2.  I just need the header to be divided, and I really don't want to use a table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant links on the "right." Try this instead:

```
.header {
    background: #FFF;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 10%;
 }

.header2 {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
 }
```

And then make sure you have a `clear` beneath so that content doesn't roll up into, something like:

```
<br style="clear: both" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  It looks like this doesn't work though!  It just does this:  http://i40.tinypic.com/20gy42d.png
I would like it to be centered on the RIGHT side (because I know my left from my right, apparently )

Comment: Hmm... you probably have some padding and/or margins in there that are making the 50% wider than actual 50%. Try pulling the percentages out. See working here: http://jsfiddle.net/bebd3/

Comment: I did this.  This is the output when done.  http://i39.tinypic.com/2r2vh91.png
Any ideas, or am I just qwopping?

Comment: You've definitely got some sort of width or something happening that isn't in my example code. Perhaps post yours to jsfiddle.